# jQuery to hide and show textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a textarea that I want to show/hide when ever I click a button
and also I need it to target this way because ill be using it in an undefined number of times

[SAMPLE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT8ij.png)

[SAMPLE IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztjie.png)

> here is the HTML that I want to

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></button>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control" id="multipleNameReq"></textarea>
```

and here is the script I try to use hiding/Showing it

```
$('body').on('click', '.buttonMultipleNameReq',function(){
    const element1 = $(this);
    const target1 = element1.parent().parent().find("#multipleNameReq");
    console.log(target1);

    if (target1.style.display === "none") {
    target1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
    target1.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

Comment: Try Jquery toggle() https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the accepted answer will work fine for nonduplicate `id` of `textarea` or any other `elements`, but as you have shown in your image if you want to work this for multiple `textarea` or any `elements` I suggest you use the `class attribute` instead of the `id attribute`, [here](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.1/duplicate-id#:%7E:text=Duplicate%20IDs%20are%20common%20validation,be%20sure%20each%20is%20unique.) is the explanation for why to not use same id multiple times,

> Duplicate IDs are common validation errors that may break the accessibility of labels, e.g., form fields, and table header cells.

> To fix the problem, change an ID value if it is used more than once to be sure each is unique.

here below is some piece of code that may help you to get what are you looking for

```js
$('body').on('click', '.buttonMultipleNameReq',function(e){
    let textArea = $(e.target).parent().parent().find('textarea');
    if(textArea.css('display') == "block"){
        textArea.hide()
    }else{
        textArea.show()
    }
})
```

```css
.multipleNameReq{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">hide/show</button>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control multipleNameReq"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">hide/show</button>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control multipleNameReq"></textarea>

</div>

<div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">hide/show</button>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control multipleNameReq"></textarea>

</div>
                
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Using toggle function**

here below is simpler code using jquery toggle,  [here](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) you can read about `toggle`

```js
$('body').on('click', '.buttonMultipleNameReq',function(e){
    $(e.target).parent().parent().find('textarea').toggle();
})
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">hide/show</button>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control multipleNameReq"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">hide/show</button>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control multipleNameReq"></textarea>

</div>

<div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">hide/show</button>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control multipleNameReq"></textarea>

</div>
                
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked sir and thanks for Informing me about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you could use it's syntax:

To get element:
`$('#multipleNameReq');`

To Check if element is visible and not hidden:
`$('#multipleNameReq').is(":visible");`

To Show:
`$('#multipleNameReq').show();`

To Hide:
`$('#multipleNameReq').hide();`

A solution to add into your click function would look like:

```
 if ($('#multipleNameReq').is(":visible")) {
    $('#multipleNameReq').hide();
 } else {
    $('#multipleNameReq').show();
 }
```

Comment: it only work on first row sir.. btw thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

To access and change the style of an element you need to use the `css` function.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.buttonMultipleNameReq', function() {
  const element1 = $(this);
  const target1 = element1.parent().parent().find("#multipleNameReq");
  if (target1.css('display') === "none") {
    target1.css('display', "block");
  } else {
    target1.css('display', "none");
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" name="tname[]" class="form-control" required placeholder="req. for">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary buttonMultipleNameReq" type="button" id="button-addon2">Click<i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></button>
  </div>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="multipleNameReq" style="display: block;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Im not good at using javascript/jquery so this is a big help to me. Thanks again sir :D